# Is this a shell operculum? If yes, can I get more info on operculum

Tags: species-identification, information

I came across this strange shell some years ago and my research concluded that it was an Operculum (gastropod)(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operculum_(gastropod)) and I am interested in knowing more about the operculum.
What is its uses, how is it formed, will I fine something inside if I break it, how does the animal feed itself inside this, and so on.

Bottom View
[image: Unknown_shell_operculum]

Top View
[image: Unknown_shell2_operculum]